# Python scraper always finds differences between the previous and the current version of website while there are none

Tags: python, python-requests

I am writing a bot which checks if there have been any changes on a given website since the last time it was scraped. For that, it scrapes the website, stores its html code in a local file, then scrapes it over and over again, and, if there are differences between the new and the old versions, it overwrites the local file and prints "Triggered". The problem is that my script always finds the difference and overwrites the file even if there are no changes.

Reproducible example:

```
import requests
import time
import os

def compare(file, url):
    if os.path.isfile("./" + file):
        scrape = requests.get(url).text
        with open(file) as f:
            txt=f.read()
        if not txt == scrape:
            with open(file, "w") as f:
                f.write(scrape)
            print("Triggered")
    else:
        scrape=requests.get(url).text
        with open(file, "w") as f:
            f.write(scrape)

ceu = "https://hro.ceu.edu/find-job"
ceu_file = "ceu.html"

while True:
    compare(ceu, ceu_file)
    time.sleep(10)
```

So, the problem is that the script gets triggered every time it scrapes the website - even though the site does not change every 10 seconds. Why then `txt==scrape`in the function is always false and thus triggers the script?

Comment: Well, did you try to print the previous and current contents to see where the difference was?

Comment: It looks like it's overwriting the file in the `else` block even if `txt == scrape` - is that intentional?

Comment: One thing to try is to actually compare what you wrote to what you TRIED to write.  On some platforms, things like newlines are sent "differently", and you need to to binary read/writes to tell the difference.

Comment: Milo P - sorry, messed up indentation while copying. I corrected that. But it still does not solve the issue.

Comment: Kevin - I have just removed \r in both files and used the following: 

`output_list = [li for li in difflib.ndiff(txt, scrape) if li[0] != ' ']    `

 - to find the difference between the txt and scrape. The output is literally random, I cannot see any pattern of difference - ['+ e', '+ V', '+ z', '+ n', '+ 2', '+ j', '+ %', '+ 2', '+ F', '+ f', '+ X', '+ %', '+ 2', '+ F', '- 8', '- U', '- p', '+ l', '+ 1', '+ 3', '+ W', '+ x', '+ M', '+ i', '+ N', '+ 4', '+ Z', '+ i', '+ Z''...].
It seems there is something conceptually wrong with the approach as such...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable automatic newline conversion by setting `newline=''` to prevent newlines from being converted to your system default when writing to a file:

```
import requests
import time
import os

def compare(url, file_):
    if os.path.isfile("./" + file_):
        scrape = requests.get(url).text
        with open(file_, "r", newline='') as f:
            txt = f.read()
        if txt != scrape:
            with open(file_, "w", newline='') as f:
                f.write(scrape)
            print("Triggered")
        else:
            print('Not triggered')
    else:
        scrape = requests.get(url).text
        with open(file_, "w", newline='') as f:
            f.write(scrape)

ceu = "https://hro.ceu.edu/find-job"
ceu_file = "ceu.html"

while True:
    compare(ceu, ceu_file)
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Thank you! It does not get triggered for this particular website anymore, but it still does with some others (like "https://mau.se/en/about-us/job-offers/"). So, that was indeed part of the problem, but not the entire problem.

Comment: @AlexeyGridnev No, it was the only problem with the code you supplied. For other code/websites, analyse the difference before and after writing and you will find the new problem

Comment: @AlexeyGridnev Just for fun, I checked the difference. The site dynamically generates a new id for a div each time. This creates a real difference on the website, however not one I think you actually care about.